# Spring Boot: Adding a record with current user ID as foreign key

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a mini project with spring boot for the creation of a calendar in which any registered user can add events to his calendar.The problem is that when I complete the form to insert the event in the database I don't understand how to add the user id as a foreign key of the event.

This is my User.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>();

}
```

This is my Event.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "event_title", nullable = false)
    private String eventTitle;

    @Column(name = "event_description", nullable = false)
    private String eventDescription;

    @Column(name = "event_date", nullable = false)
    private String eventDate;

    @Column(name = "start_time", nullable = false)
    private int startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time", nullable = false)
    private int endTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

This is the controller I use to display the form and save the record

```
@GetMapping("/events/create")
    public String createEvent(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails, Model model) {
        String email = userDetails.getUsername();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(email);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("event", new Event());
        return "/events/create";
    }
@PostMapping("/events/createevent")
    public String store(@ModelAttribute("event") Event formEvent, Model model) {

        eventService.saveOrUpdate(formEvent);
        return "redirect:/calendar";
    }
```

Comment: gotta call `event.setUser(user);` before returning the value on `createEvent`. Then it should still be set on `store()`. Or since you pass the model around, you can set it in `store()` methode

Comment: Thank you so much, i set this in `store()` and now it works!